# Sum of following elements in array CUDA

Tags: c++, arrays, cuda, parallel-processing

At first I'd like to notice that I've read about
[sum reduction](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/samples/6_Advanced/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf), but it's not what I want to achieve.

Let's say I have array with elements:

```
array[0] = 2
array[1] = 1
array[2] = -1
array[3] = 3
array[4] = -1
array[5] = 2
```

Result should be:

```
array[0] = array[0] = 2
array[1] = array[0] + array[1] = 2 + 1 = 3
array[2] = -1 (when -1 omitting)
array[3] = array[0] + array[1] + array[3] = 2 + 1 + 3 = 6 (ommited array[2] due to -1 value)
array[4] = -1 (omitting)
array[5] = array[0] + array[1] + array[3] + array[5] = 2 + 1 + 3 + 2 = 8
```

In general it should be:

```
array[0] = array[0]
array[1] = array[0] + array[1]
array[2] = array[1] + array[2]
array[3] = array[2] + array[3]
array[4] = array[3] + array[4]
array[5] = array[4] + array[5]

or just

array[n] += array[n-1] where n > 0
```

(ommiting -1 could be added later).

And I want to do this parallel in CUDA. What is the fastest way to achieve this?

Comment: The operation you are asking about isn't a reduction, it is a prefix sum.

Comment: I know, that is why I said it's not what I want to achieve :) but thanks for giving me right name of my problem, didn't know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`thrust::inclusive_scan`](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__prefixsums.html#gafb24ad76101263038b0acaddc094d70a):

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/scan.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/transform_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <iostream>

struct omit_negative : public thrust::unary_function<int, int>
{
  __host__ __device__
  int operator()(int value)
  {
    if (value<0)
    {
      value = 0;
    }
    return value;
  }
};

int main()
{
  int array[] = {2,1,-1,3,-1,2};
  const int array_size = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
  thrust::device_vector<int> d_array(array, array + array_size);
  thrust::device_vector<int> d_result(array_size);

  std::cout << "input data" << std::endl;
  thrust::copy(d_array.begin(), d_array.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));

  thrust::inclusive_scan(thrust::make_transform_iterator(d_array.begin(), omit_negative()),
                         thrust::make_transform_iterator(d_array.end(),   omit_negative()),
                         d_result.begin());

  std::cout << std::endl << "after inclusive_scan" << std::endl;
  thrust::copy(d_result.begin(), d_result.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));

  using namespace thrust::placeholders;
  thrust::scatter_if(d_array.begin(),
                     d_array.end(),
                     thrust::make_counting_iterator(0),
                     d_array.begin(),
                     d_result.begin(),
                     _1<0
                    );

  std::cout << std::endl << "after scatter_if" << std::endl;
  thrust::copy(d_result.begin(), d_result.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

**output**

```
input data
2 1 -1 3 -1 2 
after inclusive_scan
2 3 3 6 6 8 
after scatter_if
2 3 -1 6 -1 8
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out this library.

Comment: While inclusive scan is the right algorithm, you will need a transformation to zero the negative values and a second pass to substitute in zeros. As written, this isn't what the original poster wants

Comment: @talonmies you are right of course, I modified my answer.

Comment: @KamilZ From your question I dont see which final values you need to have in the array elements which you omit in the prefix sum. `array[2] = 0` while  `array[4] = -1`, please explain

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. -1 should remain -1 and should be omitted while summing.

Comment: @KamilZ I added a `scatter_if`call to restore the `-1` entries after the prefix sum

Comment: Thanks a lot. Later I will test it to check efficience (computation time).

Comment: New question related to this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611813/using-cuda-thrust-with-arrays-instead-vectors-to-inclusive-scan)